# How can I use Selenium to find element in the new page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using this code to create a script fill data itself

Snippet #1, when done, opens a new page in the same tap after pressing login. I want to use the snippet #2 to find the button code refresh and click on it but every time I get an error, shown after this:

Snippet #1

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('the url')

user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Frm_Username')
user.send_keys('admin')

password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Frm_Password')
password.send_keys('admin')

clickLogin = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#LoginId')
clickLogin.click()

browser.implicitly_wait(20)
```

Snippet #2

```
link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Btn_ReFresh')        
link.click()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myName/Desktop/loginTest1.py", line 30, in <module>
    link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Btn_ReFresh')
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 437, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#Btn_ReFresh"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpkiy2vz8t/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpkiy2vz8t/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)
```

All I want is to find an element and click it in the new page which is opened in the same tap after script logged in?

Answer (score 0):

When you using selenium you should consider that in every page you are the browser variable should refer to that page , for example here you go to a url using `browser.get()` but when you use `clicklogin.click()` you will go to another page so browser is not reference to that page so when you use  `link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Btn_ReFresh')` it gave you error and error says unable to locate element just because browser is not in that page, to solve the problem I suggest you to see when you click on login what url should browser go then pass the `browser.get` that url. for example if it is a `a` tag , see `href` attribute of this element and pass that to `browser.get()`

Comment: thanks for your answer , I tried what you said but the same result ,, if you can give me an example by code